# How can I detect that USB disk is plugged in with Metricbeat or Filebeat?

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat, usb-drive, metricbeat

I need to detect that USB disk is plugged in with Metricbeat or Filebeat to report this to Elasticsearch server.

I need this both for Windows and for Linux.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With Filebeat, it's as easy as specifying a `log` input with the path to your USB disk volume:

```
- type: log

  # Change to true to enable this input configuration.
  enabled: true

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
   # On Mac
   - /Volumes/MY_USB_DISK/*.*
   # On Linux
   - /mnt/usb/*.*
   # On Windows (pick the right drive letter on which the USB disk is mounted)
   - F:\*.*

  fields:
    source: usb
```

Then you can start Filebeat, and as soon as the USB disk is plugged in, Filebeat will start tailing all the files matching the paths above and send them to ES.

Comment: Thanks for the good idea. But practically, I only need to know about the fact that disk connected or disconnected. No need to fetch data from them

Comment: Then neither Filebeat or Metricbeat is appropriate for this task. Why did you come to this idea?

Comment: Customer requirement.